# Default for literal values of floting point and Integer data types

Tags: java

The code below is resulted to the compiler error in java

```
float variable = 123.4
```

And it is because of the fact that the default for the floating point literal value is **Double** data type. So, we should cast the literal value to the float in advance or declare the variable as double in order to solve this issue.
As we know the default for the integer literal value is **Integer** data type. However, there is no compiler error when we declare a **Byte** variable like the example below

```
byte variable = 123
```

I want to know why we do not have to cast 123 to **Byte** data type if the default for integral literal value is integer.

Comment: You don't have to cast if you write `float variable = 123.4f`

Comment: There is no loss of precision storing `123` as a `byte`

Comment: I agree with @janos However, it's a common convention to use uppercase letters when initializing literals.

Comment: This is just how Java works. If you want to know the exact rules, see [paragraph 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) of the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @khelwood yes, 123 can exactly represent by a byte, and it is the question, if the default for integer literal value is int, why we do not have to cast 123 to byte in order to assign it to a byte variable

Answer (score 0):

Values of the integral types byte, short, int, and long can be created from int literals while the value fit into the type of the variable.

You can retrieve the information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

So this :

```
byte variable = 123;
```

is fine as `123` fits to a byte.

But `byte variable = 1000;`

will not compile as `1000` doesn't fit into a byte.

Comment: I think `123.4D`  also fits to a float.

Comment: @saka1029  It doesn't specify float and `123.4D` is not an int literal.

Comment: There is no doubt that we can declare a floating point literal value like this float variable=1.4 and although 1.4 is completely fit into the float data type, there is steal a compiler error and we have to cast 1.4 to the float data type in java